# How can I use (rxjava-joins) and , then and when in android

Tags: android, rx-java

How can I use the following attribute in android

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/and-then-when.html

As per documentation these are not part of the core RxJava implementation, but are found as and, then, and when in the rxjava-joins module.

how to add the rxjava-joins module ?

Comment: they have a github with a doc, and a gradle line...

Comment: got it thanks https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaJoins